# FCM notifications working in release mode but *not* from Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, I have FCM notifications setup on my `flutter` app. It works both for android an iOS in both `debug` and `release` modes.

When I create a release `apk` and test it on my phone, notifications work. But when I upload an `appbundle` to the play store, the version I download from the play store has notifications not working. The `getToken` method returns `null`, any ideas on why this could be the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have not added SHA fingerprints for your release signing key. If you have selected something like this "Let google manage and protect your app signing key (recommended)", then you should go in Play Console, and then choose your app, go to App Signing under Setup (New version of Play Console). Your fingerprint will be available below "App Signing Key Certificate", copy it, then go to Firebase Console, inside your project, go in project settings, and then finally add your copied fingerprint. then download latest Google-services.json file and add it to your project. If you have not enabled Google signing, you have to find your fingerprint from the local signed key (which you used) using keytool and then add it.

Read this: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137403?hl=en

Comment: Is it really neccessary to have the SHA fingerprint in Firebase? In the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message) they explicitely state that this is optional. `(Optional) Enter other app information: App nickname and Debug signing certificate SHA-1.`

Comment: @Bonco , At the same place, you can also see the following text, which I further quote "`How are the App nickname and the Debug signing certificate SHA-1 used within Firebase?`

**App nickname:** An internal, convenience identifier that is only visible to you in the Firebase console

**Debug signing certificate SHA-1:** A SHA-1 hash is required by Firebase Authentication (when using Google Sign In or phone number sign in) and Firebase Dynamic Links."

Comment: So, I must say that it is optional as suggested by Firebase, but it is also kind-of required by Firebase Authentication Back-End for various purposes, especially in identifying that the package added to the project is geniuely written by the project owner only. Based on my knowledge, I would further like to add that many critical functions would probably would not work as it was intended to if key is not added to the project.

Comment: Yes yes, I'm aware that this is required for Authentication, Dynamic Links, and AppCheck. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 3):

Did you add the SHA1-fingerprint of your signing key to your firebase project? Android requires you to add the SHA1 fingerprint of your keystores to firebase. You can do so in project settings in firebase console.

If you are using Google Play App Signing you need to use the SHA1 from google play since Google will replace your release signing key with the one on googles server

[image]